# rails 4 devise update user form from another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I found this post about using [devise login from another page](http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/).

I followed the instructions and tried to use it on the edit `user` form. (I generated devise views with `rails g devise:views` and my model is called `user`)

However the form is generated for new user.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post" role="form">
```

Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

### Edit:

My `html.erb` code...

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, :role => 'form' }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: can you share your complete view and the how it is rendered(the url)

Comment: This `If you are using rails 4.0+ you should be using patch instead of put for updates. You should change the method in the form_tag residing in  app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb  and the  routes.rb  file.` is from Devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)